# Convert shared layout of asp.net to html

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I recently figured that hosting a microsoft webdomain is expencive. Therefore I want to change my website to a simple HTML file with JScript and Css.

Does anyone know how i change this code from the shared-layout of my project to normal HTML code that i can paste into my index page?

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
@Styles.Render("~/css/style.css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap.css")
@Styles.Render("~/css/animate.css")
@Styles.Render("~/css/animations.css")
@Styles.Render("~/css/custom.css")


</head>

<body>

@RenderBody()

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

Comment: You might as well load the page in a browser and save the html

Answer (score 0):

Just display any page from your web site in your browser, right click on the page, and select "View page source". Copy and paste that into a new file - the HTML is all there. No need to worry about what the above Render functions do as you are capturing the HTML after it has been rendered! Next add lines to the head section to link each .css file (keeping the same order as in the original script, that's important), and move copies of those files to your new site, and that should be it.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! One question left..
I have heard that it is a smart thing to place Javascripts below the page so that the site loads faster. Is that true?

Comment: In most cases, yes, the HTML will load faster. They should go at the bottom (just before the closing </body> tag). But some plugins may carry specific instructions to place them in the head section (eg Modernizr), and some jQuery UI code as well, to avoid display changes as the page loads. While you are about it can you please click the link to mark my answer above as Accepted? - that would be appreciated.